# Pagination on AngularJS with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I'm a newbie and I am trying to create my first pagination on AngularJS

I have a list with ng-repeat like this

```
ng-repeat="vehiculo in vehiculos | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize"
```

And this is my controller

```
/* Controllers */
angular.module('vehiculoApp.controller')

// Controller listado de vehiculos
.controller('VehiculoListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Vehiculo','$log',function($scope, Vehiculo,$log) {
    $scope.orderProp = '-id';

    Vehiculo.getAll()
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $scope.vehiculos = data;
        });



$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 10;
$scope.vehiculos = [];
$scope.numberOfPages=function(){
    return Math.ceil($scope.vehiculos.length/$scope.pageSize);                
}
for (var i=0; i<45; i++) {
    $scope.vehiculos.push("Item "+i);
}

vehiculoApp.filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    start = +start; //parse to int
    return input.slice(start);
}


});
```

I have problems with the filter because Console says

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: startFromFilterProvider <-  startFromFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/unpr?p0=startFromFilterProvider%20%3C-<!-- ngRepeat: vehiculo in vehiculos | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize -->tartFromFilter
at https://www.indicemotor.com/app/lib/angular.js:78:12
at https://www.indicemotor.com/app/lib/angular.js:3546:19
at Object.getService [as get] (https://www.indicemotor.com/app/lib/angular.js:3673:39)
at https://www.indicemotor.com/app/lib/angular.js:3551:45
at Object.getService [as get] (https://www.indicemotor.com/app/lib/angular.js:3673:39)
at Parser.$filter (https://www.indicemotor.com/app/lib/angular.js:13880:24)
at Parser.filter (https://www.indicemotor.com/app/lib/angular.js:10006:19)
at Parser.filterChain (https://www.indicemotor.com/app/lib/angular.js:9997:51)
at Parser.statements (https://www.indicemotor.com/app/lib/angular.js:9972:30)
at Parser.parse (https://www.indicemotor.com/app/lib/angular.js:9851:46)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the `startFrom` filter declaration and move it outside your controller definition.

```
vehiculoApp.filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    start = +start; //parse to int
    return input.slice(start);
});
/* Controllers */
...
```